# C++ mysterious code. any security issue?

Tags: c++

```
foo(foo &afoo): va(foo,va++){
}
```

What is the security issue or problem of this code snippet.

Comment: This question is unanswerable.

Comment: Context? Is that a copy constructor?

Comment: It's hard to answer. What is the structure of "va" ?

Comment: no offense James, i don't think so....this is a tricky question my friend questioned me. He is a excellent developer .

Comment: The problem with this code is that you don't understand it.

Comment: @etarion: It's not a copy constructor, as the parameter isn't `const`.

Comment: If `foo` is a class name how can be `va(foo,va++)` legal? (except if we consider the preprocessor, of course).

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, Copy constructors can take the argument by either const or non-const reference. §12.1/10 *A copy constructor for a class X is a constructor with a first parameter of type X& or of type const X&.*

Comment: @Oli, its lack of `const` does not prevent it from being a copy constructor. A copy-constructor parameter can be any combination of `const` and `volatile`, as long as it's passed by reference.

Comment: @David, @Rob.  Interesting.  Given that a non-const parameter won't allow `foo a; foo b = a;`, I've always assumed that this didn't count as a copy constructor.  But the standard can't be wrong, I guess!

Comment: -1 if foo is a class name it won't compile, since you can't pass a type as actual argument. if foo isn't a class name it won't compile, due to the colon. so it's not the real code, and i voted to close.

Comment: @David: Aside from the fact that the code in the OP is ill-formed, in a comment to an answer below I provided an interpretation that does not yield undefined behavior. The question is unanswerable because the OP has expended no effort to try to make it answerable.

Comment: Denzell Washington!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: For more information on Denzel Washington, see [this topic](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This with g++ compiles, and I don't think there's any UB

```
struct Va
{
    Va(struct Foo&, int) {}
};

int operator++(const Va&, int) { return 42; }

struct Foo
{
    Va va;
    Foo(Foo &afoo) : va(afoo,va++) {}
};
```

to be specific `operator++` is not doing anything with the not-yet-initialized `va` data member. It's more or less like passing `*this` (as reference) or `this` (as pointer) to a base class or a function in the initialization list... it's correctly reported by some compilers as a dangerous operation but it's legal if the referenced object is not accessed (and it's actually sometimes useful if you only need the address).

Comment: the constructor definition here is just a guess at what the original code was. in the OP's code the first argument in the initializer is the class name.

Comment: Yes... I already pointed that out in a comment. I assumed the author wanted to write `va(afoo,va++)` and not `va(foo,va++)`. The original IMO could only work using preprocessor tricks, but then clearly if we allow the preprocessor there's nothing **for sure** wrong in that code.

Comment: Good idea defining `operator++` as a non-member.

Answer (score 0):

It is UB because it changes the value of va twice in a single command.
But isn't: `foo(foo &afoo): va(afoo,va++) {}`?

Comment: va++ may do nothing to the value. We don't know the structure/implementation of va, so how could we know how operator `++` is defined?

Comment: @RageD: It doesn't matter.  `va` is uninitialised at this point, so any attempt to operate on it is undefined.

Comment: @RageD: It is still UB, since `operator++` would be called on a not-yet-constructed object `va`

Comment: My comment was for a general case. `va` taking two arguments on its constructor and `va++` changing its state. No need for -1.

Comment: @Johannes: Yes, that's what I was trying to get at with my comment!

Comment: Actually, `va` could be a function-like macro too: assuming there is a member variable `m_`, we could have `#define va(x, y) m_()`. That would not exhibit undefined behavior.  Asking what is wrong with an ill-formed, two-line partial code snippet is almost always pointless.

Comment: -1 the code can't compile and therefore can't have UB.

Comment: @Oli removed my comment because I was wrong.